# Unable to click on dropdown list (Data table responsive) when page is shrink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

i have incorporated datatable into my table. However when i am unable to click on Times/Week and Remarks when the page is shrink. It works perfectly when it is on full page.

Any idea how i can solve this?

Each time a user click on add new row, this code below will be triggered.

```
$("#addNew").click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/AssignExercisesViewModel/InitialiseExercises",
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (result) {

                    if (rowCount <= 9) {
                        // $('#TempTable4').append(html);
                        var index = '<tr style="border:1px solid black" class="exercise-records"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + (rowCount + 1) + '&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>'

                        var tblRow = '<td><select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExerciseRegionID must be a number." id=ddlRegion' + rowCount + ' name=[' + rowCount + '].ExerciseRegionID><option value="">Select an Exercise Region</option>';
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length ; i++) {
                            tblRow += '<option value= ' + result.data[i].Value + '>' + result.data[i].Text + '</option>';
                        }

                        var tblRow1 = '</td><td><select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExerciseTypeID must be a number." id=ddlType' + rowCount + ' name=[' + rowCount + '].ExerciseTypeID><option value="">Select an Exercise Type</option>'
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.data2.length; i++) {
                            tblRow1 += '<option value=' + result.data2[i].Value + '>' + result.data2[i].Text + '</option>'
                        }

                        var tblRow2 = '</td><td><select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExerciseID must be a number." data-val-required="The ExerciseID field is required." id=ddlExercise' + rowCount + ' name=[' + rowCount + '].ExerciseID><option value="">Select an Exercise</option><option value="">Select an Exercise</option>'
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.data3.length; i++) {
                            tblRow2 += '<option value=' + result.data3[i].Value + '>' + result.data3[i].Text + '</option>'
                        }

                        var tblRow3 = '</td><td><select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Number_Of_Reps must be a number." data-val-required="The Number_Of_Reps field is required." name=[' + rowCount + '].Number_Of_Reps><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>' +
                        '<option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option>' +
                        '<option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option></select></td>'

                        var tblRow4 = '<td><select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Number_Of_Secs_PositionHold must be a number." data-val-required="The Number_Of_Secs_PositionHold field is required." name=[' + rowCount + '].Number_Of_Secs_PositionHold><option value="0">0 secs</option><option value="5">5 secs</option><option value="10">10 secs</option>' +
                        '<option value="15">15 secs</option><option value="20">20 secs</option><option value="25">25 secs</option><option value="30">30 secs</option></select></td>'

                        var tblRow5 = '<td><select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Number_Of_Sets_Per_Day must be a number." data-val-required="The Number_Of_Sets_Per_Day field is required." name=[' + rowCount + '].Number_Of_Sets_Per_Day><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>' +
                        '<option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option></select></td>'

                        var tblRow6 = '<td><select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Frequency_Per_Week must be a number." data-val-required="The Frequency_Per_Week field is required." name=[' + rowCount + '].Frequency_Per_Week><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>' +
                        '<option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option></select></td>'

                        var tblRow7 = '<td><textarea class="form-control" cols="20" name=[' + rowCount + '].Remark rows="2"></textarea></td></tr>'


                        tblRow += '</select>';
                        tblRow += '</td>';
                        tblRow1 += '</select>';
                        tblRow1 += '</td';
                        tblRow2 += '</select>';
                        tblRow2 += '</td>';
                        tblRow3 += '</select>';
                        tblRow3 += '</td>';
                        tblRow4 += '</select>';
                        tblRow4 += '</td>';
                        tblRow5 += '</select>';
                        tblRow5 += '</td>';
                        tblRow6 += '</select>';
                        tblRow6 += '</td>';
                        tblRow7 += '</select>';
                        tblRow7 += '</td>';
                        oTable.fnAddData([
                            index,
                            tblRow,
                            tblRow1,
                            tblRow2,
                            tblRow3,
                            tblRow4,
                            tblRow5,
                            tblRow6,
                            tblRow7
                        ]);

                    }
                    rowCount++;
                }
            });
```

This is the button that will trigger the above codes.

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="#" id="addNew">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    Add Exercise
</a>
```

and this is the part where i declare the table to be a data table.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#TempTable2').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "order": [[0, "desc"]]
        });
    });
```

Below is the image of the dropdown box that is not working.

[image]

Comment: This probably has a lot to do with the CSS. Maybe somethings are oveerlapping. We need a [mcve]

Comment: Hi. There isn't much CSS going on other than the implementation of datatable.

Comment: can you put your page code on jsfiddle.com, so people can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi i managed to solve the problem. i simply changed the Datatable $( dt.table().body() ). Answer can be found at https://github.com/DataTables/Dist-DataTables-Responsive/commit/adc9a06bf37307612f90e8f3951609e552f590ea